# Running Dynamic Java project visible in home network

Tags: eclipse, dynamic

I have implemented Java Dynamic Project in Eclipse with Tomcat 7. I can run it on localhost and connect from client also on localhost. Now, I'd like to configure it to be able to connect from other machine in my home network.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) If you can "ping" your server from your other machines, then you should be able to connect to it.

2) By "Java Dynamic Project", I assume you mean "web project".

I assume you're now connecting locally with "http://localhost:8080/YOUR_URL"

3) Try this from another machine:

a) From a command line: `ping SERVER_NAME`

b) From a browser: `http://SERVER_NAME:8080/YOUR_URL`

4) If the connect fails, make sure your server doesn't have a firewall blocking port 8080:

- http://anythingsimple.blogspot.com/2011/09/windows-firewall-blocks-access-to.html